# LESS / javascript: convert regexp object to integer (calculation)

Tags: javascript, regex, less, eval, mixins

I want to convert the background position for vendor prefixed gradients, therefore I use a simple formula `90 - (@degree)` according to this example it should be `90 - (135) = -45`.

The important part is `.replace(/(\d*)?deg/g, 90 - '$1' + 'deg')`, I tried different functions, but no matter what, the output always ends up with NaN:
- parseInt('$1')
- parseFloat('$1')
- eval(90 - '$1')
- Number('$1')

If I replace `'$1'` with `'135'` or any other number it works nicely.

```
  @w3c:     true;   // valid w3c syntax

  @webkit:  true;   // Google Chrome, Safari, iOS
  @moz:     true;   // Mozilla Firefox
  @ms:      true;   // Internet Explorer
  @o:       true;   // Opera

  @default-background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, blue, red), linear-gradient(150deg, green, orange);

.background-image (@arguments: @default-background-image;) {
  .result (...) when (@webkit = true) {
    background-image: ~`"@{arguments}"
      .replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
      .replace("linear-gradient","-webkit-linear-gradient")
      .replace(/(\d*)?deg/g, 90 - '$1' + 'deg')`;
  }

  .result (...) when (@moz = true) {
    background-image: ~`"@{arguments}"
      .replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
      .replace("linear-gradient","-moz-linear-gradient")
      .replace(/(\d*)?deg/g, 90 - '$1' + 'deg')`;
  }

  .result (...) when (@ms = true) {
    background-image: ~`"@{arguments}"
      .replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
      .replace("linear-gradient","-ms-linear-gradient")
      .replace(/(\d*)?deg/g, 90 - '$1' + 'deg')`;
  }

  .result (...) when (@o = true) {
    background-image: ~`"@{arguments}"
      .replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')
      .replace("linear-gradient","-o-linear-gradient")
      .replace(/(\d*)?deg/g, 90 - '$1' + 'deg')`;
  }

  .result (...) when (@w3c = true) {
    background-image: @arguments;
  }

  .result (@arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a replacement *function* instead of an expression (which is evaluated as a string, causing the issue):

```
str.replace(/(\d*)deg/g, function($0, $1) {
    return (90 - parseInt($1)) + 'deg';
});
```

*I've removed the `?` because `\d*` already caters for that. Also, I would use `\d+` because an empty number doesn't make sense.*

**Example**

```
var str = '@default-background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, blue, red), linear-gradient(150deg, green, orange);';

str.replace(/(\d*)deg/g, function($0, $1) {
    return (90 - parseInt($1)) + 'deg';
});
```

Output:

```
"@default-background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, blue, red), linear-gradient(-60deg, green, orange);"
```

Comment: I've mentioned you here:
https://github.com/InitArt/mod.less/commit/4229f309a6b9b6f87924f84021c384c2b1965915

Comment: @user2425777 Much obliged ;-) btw, if you're going to reuse that conversion function, you could define it once and reference it multiple times instead to save some memory.

Comment: I'm going to think about it, altough it got a low priority for now, due to less should only be used in dev environments or be compiled to css.

By the way, I noticed, that credit to you on GitHub is pretty hidden and temporary, therefore: http://codepen.io/InitArt/pen/cgvBJ

This will be used in the documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use

`.replace(/(\d+)(?=deg)/g, 90 - parseInt($1))` where `$1` is not quoted?

It seems that java script is interpreting the quoted $1 as a string which is "not a number"

I've also converted the expression to use a non capturing forward look ahead which will eliminate the need to insert reinsert `deg` back into the replacement.

The other problem is that your regex is matching `\d*?deg` which is zero or more digits before the string `deg` I've replaced the `\d*?` with `\d+` to match 1 or more digits.

Comment: $1 is not defined, because I've used those regex substrings.
But your answer helped me very much in understanding the whole point.